# Glitch in my script moving images

Tags: javascript

I'm getting a strange glitch in my javascript (logic error) i'm not sure if its my maths or the way i have structured my code.

The idea i have is to left click and drag to scroll around a map on a canvas. It works perfectly except, when i mouse down to scroll a second time, the map resets back to its x0y0 offset.

So essentially i can't keep scrolling because as soon as i let go of the mouse and mousedown again its back to the start.

So this is how i did it:

```
//this is in the init function called on body load
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mousePos, false);
```

---

```
//relevant functions
    function mousePos(e){
            mousex = e.pageX;
            mousey = e.pageY;               
            canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", movePos, false);
    }

    function movePos(e){
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',onMouseUp,false);
    offset_x = e.pageX - mousex; //pixels to move the map along x
    offset_y =  e.pageY - mousey; //pixels to move the map along y
    }

    function onMouseUp(){
     // on mouse up stop moving the map
    canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove',movePos,false);
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You might be using `offset_x` and `offset_y` incorrectly in code that is not included here. On mouseup, you should add these values to the total offset of the map, and zero them.
2. You are adding a mouseup handler every time a mouse is moved - is that what you want? The mouseup handler should be instaled only once in `mousePos()`

Comment: Well the mouse up is what stops the map being offset - so once you left go of the mouse button the map stops moving - but i still need to get the x and y of the mouse position for click able objects at a later date. So i assumed that was the best place to put it.
The offset_x and offset_y are global vars at the top of script :
var offset_x = 0;
var offset_y = 0;

only the functions shown above changes their values.. then i use them in my draw() function. But for some unknown reason on mouse down it resets the map to its original place. =/